# registering controller plugins with front controller in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i wanted to send variables to the layout in zend framework for which i tried creating a controller plugin and placed it in

```
application
    /plugins
```

and named the file as `layout.php`, here is the code from `layout.php`

```
class Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
   public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
   {
      $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
      $view = $layout->getView();
      $view->foo = 'bar';
   }
}
```

now i wanted to register the plugin with the frontController in `application.ini` for which i tried adding

```
includePaths.plugin = APPLICATION_PATH "/plugins"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Plugin_"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugin_Layout"
```

it shows me following error.

```
Warning: include_once(Plugin/Layout.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/azhararmar/htdocs/joofris/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
```

i am new to zend framework. where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your *application.ini*:

```
pluginPaths.Plugins = APPLICATION_PATH "/Plugins"
```

Rename `resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugin_Layout"` to `resources.frontController.plugins.Layout = "Plugin_Layout"` but `frontController.plugins[]` should work anyway.

and rename your **plugin** folder to **Plugins** and your **layout.php** file to **Layout.php**, this should work.

Comment: i needed this `pluginPaths.Plugins = APPLICATION_PATH "/Plugins"` it is working now. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your path should be

```
includePaths.plugin = APPLICATION_PATH "/Plugins"
```

Note the capital P.

Comment: Make sure your plugin folder is called Plugins (with a capital P).